# How to use max method on JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

So, I was trying to use max in `JavaPairRDD` but couldn't make it work.

```
JavaPairRDD<Integer, String> someRdd = (initialisation)

String maxValue = someRdd.max()  //not working
```

My Code : http://ideone.com/0YXCJw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implement comparator which describes desired ordering:

```
import scala.Tuple2;
import java.io.Serializable;

class DummyComparator implements 
      Comparator<Tuple2<Integer, String>>, Serializable {
   public int compare(Tuple2<Integer, String> x, Tuple2<Integer, String> y) {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Pass it to the `max` method:

```
someRdd.max(new DummyComparator());
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I used.

```
class DummyComparator implements Serializable,  
     Comparator<Tuple2<Integer, String>> {
   @Override
   public int compare(Tuple2<Integer, String> o1, Tuple2<Integer, String> o2) {
         return Integer.compare(o1._1(), o2._1());
   }
}
```