# Spark: find max key in a JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark, rdd, comparator, keyvaluepair

I have some JavaPairRDD's that look like `JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<String>>` where *Integer* is number of occurences of the words contained in the *Iterable* field.

I'd like to find the JavaPairRDD associated with the maximum key-value.

signature of the JavaRDD max method looks like:

```
public static T max(java.util.Comparator<T> comp)
```

but I don't know how to implement it...

Comment: I'm not sure this will work as you expect it to, but either way are you saying you just want the max of the Integers in your RDD?

Comment: @rurgrag See my answer, there is full code of Comparator and max, without only preprocessing which you have

Answer (score 0):

Use keys() method to get maximum and then filter original RDD:

```
Integer maxKeys = originalRDD.keys().max ((x, y) -> x-y);

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<String>> withMaxKeys = originalRDD.filter (x -> x._1.equals(maxKeys))
```

or just filter original RDD - be sure, that keys are unique!

```
Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<String>> withMaxKeys = originalRDD.max ((x, y) -> x._1 - y._1);
```

`._1` means first element of a tuple, in this case it's RDD key

Instead of lambda expression, you can write i.e. (in second case):

```
public class JavaPairRDDTests {

    public static class TupleComparator implements Comparator<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<String>>>, Serializable {
        @Override
        public int compare(Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<String>> x, Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<String>> y) {
            return Integer.compare(x._1(), y._1());
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<String>> originalRDD = /* ... */;

        Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<String>> withMaxKeys = originalRDD.max(new TupleComparator());
    }

}
```

Written with help from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35385753/how-to-use-max-method-on-javapairrdd) question

Comment: I got this error:
error: incompatible types: Tuple2<Integer,Iterable<String>> cannot be converted to JavaPairRDD<Integer,Iterable<String>>

JavaPairRDD<Integer, Iterable<String>> withMaxKeys = originalRDD.max(new Comparator<Tuple2<Integer, Iterable<String>>>() {......});

Comment: @rugrag Written without compiler :/ Wait a second, I will check it

Comment: @rugrag Answer updated. I didn't change type of withMaxKeys. Be aware, that if you will have duplicated keys, then this approach will fail - then only use first approach